# Посчитать ячейки значения которых совпадают в разных листах

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet, count

Есть лист "Исходник"
Там указаны

```
место | id | приз | акция
```

Тут могут быть дубли "акции", т.к. в акции мог победить не один человек

Есть лист "Доп инфо"
Там указаны

```
акция | тип
```

Есть лист Результат
Там есть 3 колонки по разным типам

```
Призовые места - Город  | Призовые места - Обласная | Призовые места - Глобальная
```

Я пытаюсь посчитать, сколько было всего победителей во всех городских акциях.
Логика такая: формула смотрит, что находится в колонке "акция" в листе "Доп инфо" листе, если при этом в колонке "тип" там "Город", то она должна в листе "Исходник" найти все совпадения и посчитать их.

```
 =СЧЁТЕСЛИМН('Исходник'!D2:D, 'Доп инфо'!A4:A, 'Доп инфо'!B4:B, "Город" )
```

Пишу формулу, но она не работает.
Получаю ошибку "Аргументы массива в функции COUNTIFS имеют различные размеры", но не могу понять, как переделать функцию, чтобы она делала то, что мне нужно и работала.

Тут ссылка на документ с листами: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pL8TsZI5OjQEoowDyxsWr1sw26Aillzulh4cpW15E70/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Увы, так не получится. Подтягивайте тип в первую таблицу (с помощью *ВПР*), так проще будет. Иначе - формула массива (это посложнее).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**С использованием доп. формулы**

В *Исходник* в свободном столбце пишем формулу:

```
=ВПР(D2;'Доп инфо'!$A$4:$B$23;2;)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ(Исходник!$E:$E;B2)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Без использования доп. формулы**

Формула массива:

```
=СЧЁТ(ПОИСКПОЗ(Исходник!$D$2:$D$228;ЕСЛИ(B2='Доп инфо'!$B$4:$B$23;'Доп инфо'!$A$4:$A$23);))
```

Формула вводится тремя клавишами - `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`